# Is there a way to get DateTime value from timestamp type column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a select from table which does not have column that tells when row was inserted, only `timestamp` column (values like: 0x0000000000530278). Some data was imported to the table yesterday and now I need to find out what exactly was imported :(

Is there a way to do it using only `timestamp` info? [Here](http://www.sqlhacks.com/index.php/Dates/Timestamp) I found that:

- Timestamp is a 8 bytes sequential Hex number, that has nothing to do with neither the date nor the time.
- To get the current value of timestamp, use: @@DBTS.

Perhaps there is a way to find what was `timestamp` value around specific time? That would help to form a select. Or maybe there is a well known solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Transact-SQL timestamp data type is a binary data type with no time-related values.

So to answer your question: *Is there a way to get DateTime value from timestamp type column?*

The answer is: *No*

Answer (score 10):

The timestamp datatype in SQL Server 2005 is a synonym of rowversion and is just a number that is automatically incremented with each row update.

You can cast it to bigint to see its value.

To get what you want for new or updated rows, you should propably add another datetime column (lastupdate) and a trigger to update that column with each update.

For rows that have already been inserted in the past I don't think that you can do something to find the exact time.

Comment: That explains timestamp column type, but does not answer my question :|

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid it's not possible to convert/cast a TIMESTAMP to a DATETIME. 
They have entirely different uses and implementations that are incompatible.

See this link
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/timestamps-vs-datetime-data-types

Books on-line also says http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631.aspx

> The SQL Server timestamp data type has
>   nothing to do with times or dates. SQL
>   Server timestamps are binary numbers
>   that indicate the relative sequence in
>   which data modifications took place in
>   a database. The timestamp data type
>   was originally implemented to support
>   the SQL Server recovery algorithms.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to find what was timestamp value around specific time? Import is a rear thing, so time gap is significant (precision is not needed)

Answer (score 3):

Another answer to you question:

If the timestamp column is the only resource for you recovery (no backups etc) you may try to use the following logic

*Timestamp is simply a value of a counter that is incremented for each insert or update operation that is performed on a table that contains a timestamp column*.

If the data import that happened yesterday was one insert of several records you may see a sequence of numbers in the timestamp column like e.g:

```
0x00000000000007D1
0x00000000000007D2
0x00000000000007D3
0x00000000000007D4
0x00000000000007D5
```

The most recent sequence can be your added data (of course it is not guarantied)
You con combine that knowledge with other things (like auto-increment column if you use them) to identify the records you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Other people correctly pointed out that the timestamp is a binary counter.
Nevertheless, if in any table of your database, you have the timestamp and the datetime when it was recorded, you can use that piece of information to go from any timestamp to a date range. 
A log table is a good candidate for this purpose. Assuming your import table is "invoices", you could use a query like the following:

```
WITH TS 
AS
(
SELECT 
    L1.LastDateUpdated, COALESCE(L2.LastDateUpdated, {TS '2099-12-31 00:00:00'}) as LastDateUpdatedTo,
    L1.[TIMESTAMP], L2.[TIMESTAMP] as [TIMESTAMPTo]
FROM 
(
    SELECT L1.[LastDateUpdated]
          ,L1.[TIMESTAMP]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY L1.[LastDateUpdated]) ID
    FROM [Log] L1
) L1
left join 
(
    SELECT L2.[LastDateUpdated]
          ,L2.[TIMESTAMP]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY L2.[LastDateUpdated]) ID
    FROM [Log] L2
) L2 
    ON L1.ID = L2.ID - 1
)
SELECT TS.LastDateUpdated, TS.LastDateUpdatedTo, * from [Invoices]
    inner join TS ON [Invoices].Timestamp between TS.Timestamp and 
TS.TIMESTAMPTo
ORDER BY TS.TIMESTAMPTo DESC
```

Comment: Just used a trick like this to get an approx date  `DECLARE @t timestamp; SELECT TOP 1 @t = Timestamp FROM tableInNeeedDateFor ORDER BY timestamp DESC; SELECT TOP 1 @t, Datefield, timestamp  FROM FrequentlyUpdatedTable WHERE Timestamp < @t ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC`

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to restore a backup from before the inserts and compare the backuped table with the current table.

Answer (score 0):

To identify new rows by timestamp you need to keep track of the timestamps that were there beforehand.  In a pinch you could:

- Restore a previous version somewhere else.
- Copy the data from both tables into a scratch database.
- Identify the inserted data from the timestamps present in one but not the other.

With a minor risk of false positives if anything else has been going on in the DB this will get you a reasonably good difference.

For a more robust check you could calculate MD5 or SHA-1 hashes with [Hashbytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415(SQL.90).aspx) on the row contents to give you a difference with a very low probability of collision (see this wikipedia article on [Birthday attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) for a discussion of this problem).

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late but might help someone else.

Timestamp/RowVersion can be casted to BigInt but in any mean it cannot be compared to datetime.

Following statement is taken from MSDN

> The Transact-SQL [rowversion](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) data type is not a date or time data type. **timestamp** is a deprecated synonym for **rowversion**.

For more detail refer [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx)