# Need date format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working to develop a site with PHP and SQL Server, here I need to convert the date format of the timestamp unit. I asked google, but I didn't get clear idea. Kindly let me know, if any one knows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server's `Timestamp` is an sequential numeric value, but it doesn't hold any actual date or time information.

So it's not possible to convert it into a date.

See this answer:
[Is there a way to get DateTime value from timestamp type column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177970/is-there-a-way-to-get-datetime-value-from-timestamp-type-column-ms-sql-2005)