# TIMESTAMP means?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, datetime, timestamp

How to read the timestamp value. I have following value in database of MySql of table with column data type of timestamp.

1330924788

What does this number means? How to evaluate the days, hours, min, sec from this number. And when we can use the timestamp and why?

Comment: how to read this number 1330924788 of timestamp

Answer (score 3):

It's a [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), meaning seconds since 01.01.1970.

Most languages save their date and time information internally in that format and provide methods or classes to deal with it.

In PHP, e.g., you can use `date` to format such a timestamp in any way you want. In JavaScript uses the `Date`object.

I prefer to use such timestamps over the MySQL format, because it makes calculations with dates/times much easier. You can simply subtract two timestamps from each other to get the interval between them in seconds. Remembering that `60s = 1m`, `60m = 1h` and so on, you can easily have queries like `Show me everything that is at least [x]m in the past`.

Answer (score 1):

A timestamp is a sequence of characters, denoting the date or time at which a certain event occurred. It's the time at which an event is recorded by a computer, not the time of the event itself.

But What you expecting is **[UNIX TIMESTAMP](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)** It's a way to track time as a running total of seconds. This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970. Therefore, the unix time stamp is merely the number of seconds between a particular date and the Unix Epoch. This is very useful to computer systems for tracking and sorting dated information in dynamic and distributed applications both online and client side.

Answer (score 0):

Its a unix timestamp 
use **from_unixtime**

try this query

```
  SELECT from_unixtime(dateField) FROM tableName;
```

Comment: I think this question is for SQL Server. Does this still apply?

Answer (score 0):

Since you used the [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag as well:

Microsoft SQL Server has a `timestamp` type too.
But unlike MySQL, SQL Server's `timestamp` is just a sequential number which doesn't contain any date or time information.

See this answer:
[Need date format in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8135550/6884)