# Convert MySQL timestamp field to SQL Server 2005 Date field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have been Googling this for more than an hour now, without any luck.

Imported a MySQL database via CSV into MS SQL Server 2005, where a Tstamp (timestamp) field has been hassling me.

How do I convert the tstamp field into a SQL date field?

```
Select *,
  DATEADD(SECOND, field8047, 1970/01/01) as datetime_created_calc
  From [Majestic].[dbo].[hdiyouth]
```

New error message: Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.

Comment: I think you just need `DATEADD(SECONDS, <number of seconds>, 0)`.  If the number of seconds is too big.  Break it into pieces add the days first, then the seconds.  *(`x / (60 * 60 * 24)` to get days.  `x % (60 * 60 * 24)` to get seconds.)*

Comment: Tried your suggestion, getting this error message:
Msg 321, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
"SECONDS" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.

Comment: Try `SELECT DATEADD(SECONDS, [hdiyouth].[Tstamp], 0) FROM [Majestic].[dbo].[hdiyouth]`. (Or whatever your TSamp field is called).

Comment: Same error as listed on top. It doesnt like Varchar apparently

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177970/is-there-a-way-to-get-datetime-value-from-timestamp-type-column>

Comment: @Taeeril. I'm referring to MySQL tstamp (1318543200) while you are referring to T-SQL. To work out the date in Excel: +1318543200/60/60/24+"1970/01/01"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that field8047 is a `varchar` field.

Try this:

```
Select *,
  DATEADD(SECOND, cast(field8047 as int), '19700101') as datetime_created_calc
  From [Majestic].[dbo].[hdiyouth]
```

Comment: Magic stuff!! Thank you this is the one!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a VARCHAR() that represents a numeric type, and that numeric type represents the number of seconds from a fixed date.

CAST your VARCHAR() into a numeric type.

Then use that number in DATEADD().

If the number is too big, break it up into DAYS and SECONDS.

```
SELECT
  DATEADD(
    DAYS,
    CAST([hdiyouth].[Tstamp] AS BIGINT) / (60*60*24),
    DATEADD(
      SECONDS,
      CAST([hdiyouth].[Tstamp] AS BIGINT) % (60*60*24),
      0
    )
  )
FROM
  [Majestic].[dbo].[hdiyouth]
```

If it's giving the right time, but the wrong date, change the `0` to whatever date your timestamp should be based from.

Comment: Error message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ' '.
SELECT
  DATEADD(
    DAYS,
    CAST([hdiyouth].[field8047] AS BIGINT) / (60*60*24),
    DATEADD(
      SECONDS,
      CAST([hdiyouth].[field8047] AS BIGINT) * (60*60*24),
      0
    )
  )
FROM
  [Majestic].[dbo].[hdiyouth]

Answer (score 0):

cast your field to integer.

```
Select  DATEADD(SECOND, CAST(field8047 AS INTEGER), '1970/01/01')
Select  DATEADD(SECOND, CAST('60' AS INTEGER), '1970/01/01')
```

Comment: Make sure you have quotes or something around your dates.