# How razor convert byte[8] to string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, encoding

In my table there is a column with datatype of timestamp. Using entity framework I can get the value of this timestamp value and it's a byte[] value.

Once this value is sent to view, it's generate a string value. (I'm using razor engine)

My byte[] is [0,0,0,0,0,1,159,44] and once it converted to string using razor it's like AAAAAAABnyw=

My question is how this string value be like this? 
What's the encoding method used by the razor?

How do I get this string value from byte[8] using C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What's the encoding method used by the razor?

Well that just looks like Base64 to me:

```
byte[] x = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 159, 44};
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(x));
```

Output: AAAAAAABnyw=

You can go the other way with `Convert.FromBase64String`.

Alternatively, you might want to use [`BitConverter.ToInt64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint64) to retrieve the original 64-bit integer [which corresponds to `rowversion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177970/is-there-a-way-to-get-datetime-value-from-timestamp-type-column), I believe.

Comment: I thought the point was sql timestamps were not actual `Date` or `DateTime` instances, but instead were a numerically unique number based on time. (Perhaps im thinking of `rowversion`)

Comment: @Jamiec: Looks like you're right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177970/is-there-a-way-to-get-datetime-value-from-timestamp-type-column Will delete that part :)

Comment: @Jamiec Numerically unique ascending not-based-on-time from what I know... mmmh checked "based on relative time"